# Very bad camera image quality

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I'm trying to save image taken from camera in my phone. It works but the quality of images is very bad.
First,  for the intent, this is my code :

```
intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

And for ativity result, I tried this :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PICTURE)
    {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
          bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "", null);
      Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
        }
```

Can you please help me to resolve this problem ?

Comment: "I'm trying to save image taken from camera in my phone" -- why don't you use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and have the camera app save the image for you?

Comment: why are you scaling your image?

Comment: @CommonsWare : How can I do it please ?

Comment: @MarkoLazić : Even I do not scale my image, the quality is still very bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to be on disk, let the camera app do it. Add an `EXTRA_OUTPUT` `Uri` to your `Intent`, pointing to where you want the image to be stored.

```
package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File dir=
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    output=new File(dir, "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), "image/jpeg");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content))

The `Uri` needs to point to a place where the camera app can write, such as external storage.

Comment: Why is the CONTENT_REQUEST constant set to 1337? Is it just a random number?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa: It needs to be an integer. You are welcome to choose another integer that suits you. *If* your activity is calling `startActivityForResult()` in multiple places for multiple distinct requests, you will want distinct request code integers for each, so your `onActivityResult()` can tell them apart.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I see... Appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. I use the similar code as yours, but I observe a difference in the quality of image captured using this code and the native android camera, if you have any clue please throw some insight into this.
Specifics of the size:-
Native camera - around 1.5 MB
Using above code - 400 kb.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: "I observe a difference in the quality of image captured using this code and the native android camera" -- take it up with the developers of the camera app that you chose (as a user) when your code started the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity. There is no requirement for a camera app to offer the same quality (or anything else) between images taken via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and via other means from within the same camera app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your Insightful explanation. So ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE actually invokes a camera with some default settings, the camera app may have different settings, this is what I understand, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: "So ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE actually invokes a camera with some default settings" -- it invokes the camera app that the user chooses. "the camera app may have different settings" -- the camera app may behave differently when launched via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and something else, like a home screen launcher icon.