# Overcoming Photo Results from Android Cameras That Produce Low Resolution

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want to take a picture from the Camera and Upload it to Server, but when I take a Picture from the Camera and Upload the Picture is low Resolution.

Code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CaptureImageFromCamera = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    CaptureImageFromCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1)
            try {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) throws IOException {
    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes;
    bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "DCA/Attachment/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImageViewHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Can be seen that the image quality is low resolution.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

**[UPDATE] HOW I TO SOLVE THIS**

I read the article [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/) to solve this problem

Note: Read from the start page

Comment: May this helpful for you, You can try this! https://stackoverflow.com/a/21238037/7498057

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package com.example.admin.camsdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button captureimage;
ContentValues cv;
Uri imageUri;
ImageView imgView;
    public static final int PICTURE_RESULT=111;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        captureimage=(Button)findViewById(R.id.opencamera);
        imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        captureimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "My Picture");
                cv.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From Camera");
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case PICTURE_RESULT:
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                          Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                    getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                            imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where i added cv = new ContentValues(); ? can you give the full source?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Ok I understand, but what about the `ImageUploadToServerFunction` function?

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/

Comment: check this link

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fgXsTbDF this is my code

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: if my answer help you then please check correct

Comment: This solution worked for me but if you have another class which opens the activity make sure the passed URI is the same because inserting new CV changes the URI

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener` and `camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, pictureCallback)`

Answer (score 0):

For images taken from camera, you should consider JPEG compression. PNG is more suitable for icons where the colors used are few.

Comment: I've tried using JPEG but the result is the same